# Arduino UNO + ESP8266 WiFi Relay by LC Technology

Tags: esp8266, relay

I have Arduino Uno, and recently obtained ESP8266 WiFi Relay by LC Technology. I tried to look up some information about that on the net, but all the answers / suggested solution didn't work for me. Let me briefly explain the problem.

I have connected this module to arduino in a very simple way:

- TX -> pin 7
- RX -> pin 6
- 5V -> IN +
- GND -> IN -

Simple code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define TxPin 7
#define RxPin 6

SoftwareSerial ESPrelay(RxPin, TxPin);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    ESPrelay.begin(9600);

    readRx();

    ESPrelay.println("AT");
    readRx();
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println(ESPrelay.read());
    // this above is constant -1
}

void readRx() {
    String msg = "";
    while (ESPrelay.available()) {
        char rxByte = ESPrelay.read();
        msg += rxByte;
    }
    Serial.println(msg);
    delay(500);
}
```

I can see WiFi AP created by the module - so I think module itself works fine - communication between Arduino and module is somewhat broken.

I tried all different AT commands, but none of them seems to take an effect (tried switching modes and connecting to home WiFI, but no luck) also, no response is returned. Could someone try and help me debug this issue?

I tried changing 9600 to 115200 when communicating, but no luck with this either.

[image]

Comment: Did you remove the ESP-01 from the relay board?

Comment: No, I didn't...

Comment: and how did you wire it then?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/xoNjI62 - from the left: 1) IN+ -> 5V 2) IN- -> GND 3) RXD -> pin 6 4) TXD -> pin 7

Comment: connect everything to the pins header, not to screw terminals. the IN terminals are for powering the relay coil

Comment: I did now, and nothing has changed. Still 0 response for AT and AT+RST commands.

Comment: you should connect RX to TX.  TX to 6 and RX to 7

Comment: so the other way around than what I had? Sorry got a little bit confused. I tried connecting it the other way around and still nothing... Are you willing to hop on discord chat?  Might be easier/faster to communicate...

Comment: call read readRx in the loop(). add delay before sending "AT" in setup to let the esp8266 time to boot

Comment: I had 115200 set up before, hence was not seeing anything. Changed back to 9600 and I can see response from the module!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serial connection requires connecting transmit TX pin to receive RX pin. Your SoftwareSerial pins ar pin 6 RX and pin 7 TX. So your wiring should be esp8266 TX to Uno pin 6 and esp8266 RX to Uno pin 7.

Connect 5 V and ground to the pins header, not to screw terminals. The IN terminals are for powering the relay coil.

Call read readRx() in the loop(). Add delay before sending "AT" in setup to let the esp8266 time to boot.